# show Label Back Color Name on Item Click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DataList with a Label which shows some colors for a Product. I want these Colors to be clicked and Print Name of the Color. Here is how i am showing colors using a DataList. When User Clicks a label The Name of the color should show(i.e Red, Black) and also go in the Database against that Product. Please Guide how i can Print the Name of the Color and also make this a Clickable Label inside DataList. Thanks in Advance

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dtlcolor" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="lblcolorID" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblcolor" Width="25px" Height="25px" BackColor='<%# System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Eval("Color").ToString())%>'></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Any Idea Guys.. help is much needed at this point of time . thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to make the labels clickable is to use LinkButtons instead. They look like pretty much the same (you could use css if you wish) and they offer the OnClick event. You can also use javaScript code instead and add onclick event.

Anyway, the following code that can be set to your OnClick event will get the color from your linkButton and show in a new ColourLblID label.

```
protected void ShowColour(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton colourButton = (LinkButton)sender;
    ColourLblID.Text = colourButton.BackColor.Name;
}
```

Comment: NO Mate Sorry doesn't Work.. Page Post Backs on Button Click which is not Required.. on DataList Item Click it should display the Name of the COlour without a PostBack... Thanks

Comment: OK then, you should use javaScript. Try this. Add an onclick event in your label like this 
 onclick="showListItemColour(this.id)" 

Next create a javaScript function to show your colour in a new span.
 
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function showListItemColour(labelID) {
            var label = document.getElementById(labelID);
            var colour = label.style.backgroundColor;

            document.getElementById("colourSpanID").innerHTML = colour;

        }

        </script>